# How can the DB instance know that it should be placed in the private address range specified inside a VPC?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops

I was looking at Terraform's documentation on how to [configure a private IP for a SQL database](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance#private-ip-instance). There, they configure a private address inside a VPC.

```
resource "google_compute_global_address" "private_ip_address" {
  provider = google-beta

  name          = "private-ip-address"
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  prefix_length = 16
  network       = google_compute_network.private_network.id
}

resource "google_service_networking_connection" "private_vpc_connection" {
  provider = google-beta

  network                 = google_compute_network.private_network.id
  service                 = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.private_ip_address.name]
}
```

Afterwards, they configure the DB and specify the network (not the private address):

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "instance" {
  provider = google-beta

  name             = "private-instance-${random_id.db_name_suffix.hex}"
  region           = "us-central1"
  database_version = "MYSQL_5_7"

  depends_on = [google_service_networking_connection.private_vpc_connection]

  settings {
    tier = "db-f1-micro"
    ip_configuration {
      ipv4_enabled    = false
      # Why is the network and not the address referenced?
      private_network = google_compute_network.private_network.id
    }
  }
}
```

How can the DB instance know that it should be placed in the private address range specified? Is everything going to be placed in that range? are existing resources moved to those IPs? What happens if more than one `google_service_networking_connection` is defined? How the DB instance 'decides' where to go?

Also, what happens if I define a range of 1 address (10.0.0.1/32)? Is it going to be enough for 1 db instance?

Answer (score 3):

When you create a Cloud SQL with a private IP, you must use a network service connection, that you define here

```
resource "google_service_networking_connection" "private_vpc_connection" {
  provider = google-beta

  network                 = google_compute_network.private_network.id
  service                 = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.private_ip_address.name]
}
```

Because of that, the Cloud SQL instance knows that it has to use an IP in the `reserved_peering_ranges`, and pick one free.

On the range reservation, you can define the first IP of the range like that

```
resource "google_compute_global_address" "private_ip_address" {
  provider = google-beta

  name          = "private-ip-address"
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  prefix_length = 16
  network       = google_compute_network.private_network.id
  address = <first IP of the range>
}
```

Finally, you can't reserve a range of 1 IP for a service networking connection. /24
is the smallest range that you can use. /16 is the recommended one.